# How to find touches on button using timer

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have button event. If single tap(touch) on button i am doing Flip action . If Double tap on button i am doing another action that is unhidden other button. Both same button event.i tried in image touches but not getting. How to find single tap or double Tap on button  . how to implement timer to find touches  any sample or tutorial ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might get you started..

(i have used 0.5 for a timeout value, but you might want to change this)

```
    -(void)butonEvent:(id)sendr{


    if(buttonTimer)[self doublePress];
    else
    {

    //buttonTimer is a local NSTimer

    buttonTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.5
                     target: self
                     selector: @selector(handleTimer:)
                     userInfo: nil
                     repeats: NO];
    }

    }


    -(void)singlePress{
[buttonTimer invalidate];buttonTimer=nil;//edit
    NSLog(@"Single Press");
    }

    -(void)doublePress{
[buttonTimer invalidate];buttonTimer=nil;//edit
    NSLog(@"doublePress");
    }

    -(void)handleTimer:(id)sendr
    {        
    [self singlePress];
    }
```

Comment: I am getting  problem double tapping . its taking double action as well as single after set itme

Comment: Yes its working .Thank you very much.   Plz  share me study link related Touches .

Comment: "Plz share me study link related Touches" - i don't understand

Comment: That is Basic study documents related  UIbutton ,label ,image touches link

Comment: this is the where apple keeps all its documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There is two options in UIButton Events,

You can use the following to detect,
   single touch through **TouchDown**,
   double touch through  **TouchDownRepeat**.
You can connect ur UIButtons using IB same way as like TouchUpInside and write ur coding accoring to that.

Comment: Never used TouchDownRepeat but is it sensible to assume that assigning both to a button and double tapping would would fire both events and need a timer anyway?

Comment: I think,wen we go for continuous double click both will not be triggered.Only one will be fired.